# What would occur after the summation of two sequences that diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are divergent sequences. Then the sum $$a_n + b_n = c_n$$ gives a third sequence $c_n$. Would $c_n$ be a divergent or a convergent sequence?

It seems intuitive that $c_n$ will be divergent. I tried coming up with a counter-example but I could not find one. If $c_n$ is indeed divergent, what would be a good theorem to use as a base in order to prove the claim that $c_n$ is divergent?

Comment: Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a divergent sequence and consider the divergent sequence $(-a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$.

Comment: As you can see from these helpful examples, the problem is that the divergent parts of two divergent series can "add out" to become nice and convergent again. You can start with a "good" series with terms $g_n$ and a "bad" series with terms $b_n$ and form the two "bad" series $g_n\pm b_n$ which again sum to another "good" series. This sort of trick is commonly used. It reminds me of showing two irrationals can sum to a rational by considering $a\pm \sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $a_n = n$ and $b_n=-n$? Then $c_n=0$ and the series converges. On the other hand, taking $a_n=b_n=n$ ensures that $c_n=2n$ and divergent.